# TypeError: Failed to fetch in React using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api, request-promise

I using React and I am creating an application that integrates the backend as well. I am trying to fetch data from my backend. I have started both the frontend and the backend, and, using Thunderclient, checked that the endpoint is working fine. But whenever I am trying to fetch the same data using a fetch API call, I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the code snippet for the same.

```
const getNotes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/fetchall`, {
        method: "GET", 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "authtoken" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
    });
    // ...
}
```

Can someone help me out with this?

CORS has been installed and used in index.js for the backend. I also tried using `"mode": "CORS"`  but even that is not working for me.

Comment: How is `getNotes` called?

Comment: It is getting called in a separate component "Notes", using "useEffect" hook

Comment: const context =  useContext(NoteContext);
    const {notes,getNotes} = context;
    useEffect(()=>
    {
      getNotes()
    })

Comment: Use the _Network_ panel in your dev-tools to inspect the actual request. What is the value of `host`? FYI your GET request has no request body so therefore does not need a content-type request header